# SQlite WHERE clause in android don't work

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my project I use SQLiteDatabase.query function to get data from DB. The query is:

```
 Cursor c = db.query("event as ev left join logo as l ON ev.logo_id = l.logo_id",
            new String[] {"ev.event_id", "ev.name", "ev.event_date", "ev.type", "l.path"},
            "strftime('%m', 'now') <= ? OR (strftime('%d', 'now') <= ? " +
                    "AND strftime('%m', 'now') == ?)",
            new String[] {"strftime('%m', ev.event_date)", "strftime('%d', ev.event_date)",
                    "strftime('%m', ev.event_date)"}, null, null,
            "strftime('%m', ev.event_date), strftime('%d', ev.event_date) ASC", limit);
```

The contents of event table:

```
1|День Рождения|1964-09-10 00:00:00|birthday|1
2|День Рождения|1964-06-10 00:00:00|birthday|2
3|День Рождения|1985-01-01 00:00:00|birthday|3
4|День Рождения|1992-05-11 00:00:00|birthday|4
```

The contents of logo table:

```
1|/data/data/com.example.app/app_imageDir/imageavatar_14e18a68-7049-433f-9954-fb3fea6000e1.png
2|/data/data/com.example.app/app_imageDir/imageavatar_5dda2aec-   136e-468d-af04-ca6e74804765.png
3|/data/data/com.example.app/app_imageDir/imageavatar_d1626db3-3f7c-474d-8294-c498f40c6892.png
4|/data/data/com.example.app/app_imageDir/imageavatar_d2f995a1-ae3c-41fd-8bdd-c69b1566239a.png
```

As follows from the query, cursor must contain only events with event_id 1,2,4 (Tested at March 13).
But when I start application, all events appears on the screen. 
If I rewrite this query and run it from sqlite's console all works correct.

The code to get data from cursor is:

```
public List<Map<String, String>> getAll(Cursor c) {
    List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<>();
    int counter = 0;

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for (String cn : c.getColumnNames()) {
                 map.put(cn, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(cn)));
            }
            data.add(counter, map);
            counter++;
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    return data;
}
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `?` variables and argument binding only for literal values such as string literals. You cannot use it for binding expressions such as `strftime('%m', ev.event_date)` - it will be bound as a string literal.

Move the expressions to be part of the SQL query itself.